# Finding the minimum value from a Stack

Tags: java, data-structures, stack

I am trying to solve this Stack question from LeetCode, I can only pass 14/18 test cases ans as the tests are not available I am unable to figure out what edge cases is missing. I am new to Java so help appreciated :-)

```
          public class MinStack {

              private int top;
              private ArrayList<Integer> stack;
              private ArrayList<Integer> minStack;

              /** initialize your data structure here. */
              public MinStack() {
                  this.top = -1;
                  this.stack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
                  this.minStack = new ArrayList<Integer>();
              }

              public void push(int x) {
                  top++;
                  stack.add(x);
                  if(top == 0){
                      minStack.add(x);
                  }
                  else{
                      minStack.add(Math.min(minStack.get(top-1), x));

                  }
              }

              public void pop() {
                  stack.remove(stack.get(top));
                  minStack.remove(minStack.get(top));
                  top--;
              }

              public int top() {
                  if(top >= 0)
                      return stack.get(top); 
                  return -1;
              }

              public int getMin() {
                  if(top >= 0)
                      return minStack.get(top);
                  return -1;
              }
          }

          /**
           * Your MinStack object will be instantiated and called as such:
           * MinStack obj = new MinStack();
           * obj.push(x);
           * obj.pop();
           * int param_3 = obj.top();
           * int param_4 = obj.getMin();
           */
```

Comment: Has anyone tried to solve it this way?? I believe it has something to do when the Stack is empty or maybe not.

Comment: Your problem is that you're using `remove(Object o)`, when you should simply be using `remove(int index)`.

Comment: Why do you use an `ArrayList` to define a stack? You could use an array which is a simpler method.

Comment: progy_rock using just array how can I define size of the array which is not fixed

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use `Stack<Integer>` for stack and the `length` property for stack top.
2. doing `stack.remove(Object o)` removes the first occurrence of the object in the backing data structure, an ArrayList in your case. If you use `Stack<Integer>`, simply call `stack.pop()`. Or, call `stack.remove(top)` if using an ArrayList.

The algorithm looks fine to me.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error arise when your top element on the stack was pop and the user demands for the current minimum in the stack....

Consider a stack of pop operations 1,7,3,4,2, 8,9 Undoubtedly, 1 is on the head of this stack being the minimum. But if pop is called, 1 is removed... Due to no proper sorting, there is no guarantee that the next element on the top of the stack will be minimum.

in this line

minStack.add(Math.min(minStack.get(top-1), x));

and example above, 1 is always added to the stack, being the minimum. Thus, when 1 is pop out, 1 is still the minimum in your minStack but ought to be 2 from the example above

Comment: but that line only adds minimum when I push an element, when I pop stack I also pop minStack

Comment: Yea, it adds minimum every time.  for example first push will add 1; second push will add min(1, 7) i.e 1  , third push will add min(1, 3) still 1. etc. Thus, your min stack will only have 1s. When popping minStack, what you will still have has min is 1. Since,   your stack is filled with 1s

Answer (score 0):

Try out this solution.

```
    // Java program to implement a stack that supports 
// getMinimum() in O(1) time and O(1) extra space. 
import java.util.*; 

// A user defined stack that supports getMin() in 
// addition to push() and pop() 
class MyStack 
{ 
    Stack<Integer> s; 
    Integer minEle; 

    // Constructor 
    MyStack() { s = new Stack<Integer>(); } 

    // Prints minimum element of MyStack 
    void getMin() 
    { 
        // Get the minimum number in the entire stack 
        if (s.isEmpty()) 
            System.out.println("Stack is empty"); 

        // variable minEle stores the minimum element 
        // in the stack. 
        else
            System.out.println("Minimum Element in the " + 
                               " stack is: " + minEle); 
    } 

    // prints top element of MyStack 
    void peek() 
    { 
        if (s.isEmpty()) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Stack is empty "); 
            return; 
        } 

        Integer t = s.peek(); // Top element. 

        System.out.print("Top Most Element is: "); 

        // If t < minEle means minEle stores 
        // value of t. 
        if (t < minEle) 
            System.out.println(minEle); 
        else
            System.out.println(t); 
    } 

    // Removes the top element from MyStack 
    void pop() 
    { 
        if (s.isEmpty()) 
        { 
            System.out.println("Stack is empty"); 
            return; 
        } 

        System.out.print("Top Most Element Removed: "); 
        Integer t = s.pop(); 

        // Minimum will change as the minimum element 
        // of the stack is being removed. 
        if (t < minEle) 
        { 
            System.out.println(minEle); 
            minEle = 2*minEle - t; 
        } 

        else
            System.out.println(t); 
    } 

    // Insert new number into MyStack 
    void push(Integer x) 
    { 
        if (s.isEmpty()) 
        { 
            minEle = x; 
            s.push(x); 
            System.out.println("Number Inserted: " + x); 
            return; 
        } 

        // If new number is less than original minEle 
        if (x < minEle) 
        { 
            s.push(2*x - minEle); 
            minEle = x; 
        } 

        else
            s.push(x); 

        System.out.println("Number Inserted: " + x); 
    } 
};
```